# SQL optimization on the following 7 update queries. same table. Combine into one?

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-2009, advantage-database-server, sql-optimization

The following queries update the same table like 7 times.. I would appreciate your help on how I might optimize this by putting it into one query so it passes through the table only once instead of 7 times..  This is really slowing down performance on large datasets..

Thanks.

P.S. I don't know if it will still work out but each query string depends on the query before it to accurately calculate..  So if we need to keep them separate in order to keep it accurate then I could use some help optimizing each string (query) individually.

The following SQL queries are made in Delphi 2009 So the format may be a little different but you should still be able to read the query pretty easily..

```
Str1 :=
'update user set amount = ' +
  '(select round(sum(bill.amount),2) from bill where ' +
  'bill.user = user.code); ' +
'update user set pay = ' +
  '(select round(sum(bill.pay),2) from bill where ' +
  'bill.user = user.code); ' +
'update user set balance = round(amount + pay,2);';

//execute query

 Str1 :=
'update user set group_amt = ' +
  '(select sum(bill.amount) from bill where ' +
  'bill.client = user.client); ' +
'update user set group_pay = ' +
  '(select sum(bill.pay) from bill where ' +
  'bill.client = user.client); ' +
'update user set group_bal = round(group_amt + group_pay,2);';

 //execute query

Str1 :=
'update user set bal_flag = true ' +
'where abs(balance) > 0.001 and bal_flag = false;';
```

Comment: Is it a *must* that you do this as a batch process for all records?  Unless you are deleting the records after processing, you're doing a lot of repeat work.  An alternative could be to use triggers to update the dependent records every time  record in `bill` is written.

Comment: Triggers would be a good idea, however I am not very familiar with them. I will look into implementing triggers in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc?)

Comment: I'm using Advantage Database Server 9

Comment: A few thoughts:   1) You are updating all users each time these queries are run.  Do you need to do that?  Cant you do it for a specific user when they login or make changes, etc.   It might not make sense to run these queries for all users, if most users haven't made payments, etc. for sometime.  2) Balance is stored in the database?  If this is used only on the UI side, might as well calculate it on the UI side for presentation.

Comment: Yeah this code actually won't be running all the time.. It will only be used if a user suspects that their balances are off.  They can run it to hopefully fix any issues..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you can merge 6 of the updates into just 2 updates...

```
UPDATE
  user
SET
  amount   = bill.amount,
  pay      = bill.pay,
  balance  = bill.pay + bill.amount
FROM
(
  SELECT
    user,
    round(sum(bill.amount),2)   AS amount,
    round(sum(bill.pay)   ,2)   AS pay
  FROM
    bill
  GROUP BY
    user
)
  AS bill
WHERE
  bill.user = user.code
```

And nearly identically...

```
UPDATE
  user
SET
  group_amt = bill.amount,
  group_pay = bill.pay,
  group_bal = bill.pay + bill.amount
FROM
(
  SELECT
    client,
    round(sum(bill.amount),2)   AS amount,
    round(sum(bill.pay)   ,2)   AS pay
  FROM
    bill
  GROUP BY
    client
)
  AS bill
WHERE
  bill.client = user.client
```

Comment: Thank you for the help in optimizing this query.